# Draw rectangle with it's center at coordinates

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I'm currently building a small game on an HTML5-Canvas. The player controls a rectangle and the rectangle draws a line on it's way. I'm storing the coordinates of the way the rectangle goes and create a line from them. The problem is, that the rectangle's coordinates are the position of it's top-left corner. Is there any way to draw the rectangle with the center on it's coordinates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pass new cordinates to the function that draws the rectangle:

```
newX = x - width / 2
newY = y - height / 2
```

**Example:**

```
function fillRectCentered(context, x, y, width, height) {
    context.fillRect(x - width / 2, y - height / 2, width, height);
}
```

Comment: Wow that was easy! Thank You! I didn't know about the fillRect function, I called rect() and then fil()

Answer (score 0):

If it is any help, here is my code from Game Maker.

```
///draw_rectangle(x,y,w,h,col,alpha,[rot])
/*
    Draw rectangle from centre point.
*/

var px, py,
ox = argument[0], //centre point, pixels
oy = argument[1], //centre point, pixels
w = argument[2], //width, pixels
h = argument[3], //height, pixels
col = argument[4], //colour
alpha = argument[5],
a, b, c, ang,
rot = 0;

if (argument_count > 4) rot = argument[6];

draw_primitive_begin(pr_trianglestrip);

a = w/2;
b = h/2;
c = sqrt(sqr(a) + sqr(b))
ang = darctan(b/a);

px = ox + lengthdir_x(c, rot - ang);
py = oy + lengthdir_y(c, rot - ang);
draw_vertex_colour(px, py, col, alpha)

px = ox + lengthdir_x(c, rot + ang);
py = oy + lengthdir_y(c, rot + ang);
draw_vertex_colour(px, py, col, alpha)

px = ox + lengthdir_x(c, rot + ang + 180);
py = oy + lengthdir_y(c, rot + ang + 180);
draw_vertex_colour(px, py, col, alpha)

px = ox + lengthdir_x(c, rot - ang + 180);
py = oy + lengthdir_y(c, rot - ang + 180);
draw_vertex_colour(px, py, col, alpha)

draw_primitive_end();
```